# Onerror directives not working with Solr data import handler / PDFBox

Tags: solr, pdfbox, dataimporthandler

we are trying to index about 10,000 PDFs against a MySQL table. We are using Solr 5.2.1, Tika 1.7 and PDFBox 1.8.8. Data import handler keeps giving various errors, which halts the entire process. Most errors have to do with unreadable content or PDF file not found. I understand this, and would like the process to continue or skip past the problem files. But no matter how I set the onerror directive, it does not seem to work. We have indexed smaller sets of PDFs using the same methods, no problem. But the continuous errors on this larger store are stopping us in our tracks! I would appreciate any advice.

Here is entity from data-config.xml:

```
<entity name="proceedings" dataSource="proceedings_db" onerror="skip"
    query="SELECT productID, title, fileName, buildDate
    FROM products 
    WHERE status = '1' 
">
    <field column="productID" name="uid" />
    <field column="title" name="paper_title" />
    <field column="fileName" name="filename" />
    <field column="buildDate" name="builddate" />

    <entity name="file" dataSource="proceedings_files" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" url="${proceedings.filename}" format="text" onerror="skip"> 
    </entity>
</entity>
```

I  have tried setting onerror for the outer entity, for the inner, and for both (as above). I have tried skip and continue for all of those combinations. It seems to have no impact.

Here is an example of an error I get:

```
ERROR FlateFilter FlateFilter: stop reading corrupt stream due to a DataFormatException
```

and

```
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.MemoryTTFDataStream.readSignedShort(MemoryTTFDataStream.java:139)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.HorizontalMetricsTable.initData(HorizontalMetricsTable.java:62)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.initializeTable(TrueTypeFont.java:280)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.AbstractTTFParser.parseTables(AbstractTTFParser.java:128)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:80)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.AbstractTTFParser.parseTTF(AbstractTTFParser.java:109)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.AbstractTTFParser.parseTTF(AbstractTTFParser.java:84)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.getTTFFont(PDTrueTypeFont.java:632)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.getFontWidth(PDTrueTypeFont.java:673)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.getFontWidth(PDSimpleFont.java:231)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processEncodedText(PDFStreamEngine.java:411)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowTextGlyph.process(ShowTextGlyph.java:62)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:557)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:460)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:385)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:344)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.process(PDF2XHTML.java:134)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:256)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:256)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor.nextRow(TikaEntityProcessor.java:162)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:514)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
```

These are not the only errors, mind you, but they are representative. I'd prefer not to hunt down and zap every offending PDF, but if that is what it takes, then fine. But as with the error above, I don't even get a filename, even if I broaden the log output settings. Sometimes I do, and I zap that file, but it does not happen each time.

I guess I do not understand what purpose the onerror settings serve, when it seems like the only working option is to stop! Again, I'd be most appreciative of any advice or suggestions as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: current PDFBox version is 2.0.11 or 1.8.15.

Comment: If you have any PDF files that brings errors on the latest version other than IOException (e.g. nullpointererror, classcastexception or arrayoutofboundsexception), please open an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX . If you can't share the files, do still open an issue but make sure to include the whole stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Tilman, I will take a look. My issue is not so much with the errors themselves, though. It's more to do with 1) Data Import Handler not doing what I'd like it to do when it DOES hit an error, and 2) not always giving me the filename for whatever file is causing the problem, even though I set most of the PDFBox log settings to "all." Sometimes the error messages give the filename; sometimes not.

Comment: PDFBox may sometimes output stack traces, but if the calls are not aborted then it means PDFBox was able to recover from that and tries to keep working. So these would result in you not knowing what file was "bad".

Answer (score 0):

using the DIH to index large ammount of PDF files in a real prod environment is NOT a good idea:

1. some pdfs will fail to be extracted, no matter what. If you need to extract content by any means, you should catch the errored ones and use a second extraction library (different from PDFBox), as no two libraries fail with the same set of files.
2. some will OOM, same as above, try other library if needed when your process continues.
3. Worse, some pdfs will hang while extracting. You need to setup some infra to find those cases, and kill the extracting process so it goes on to the next ones. Ditto on the second library if you feel like.

Bottomline, you should use some other setup by using some ETL tools, or just write some custom code to do the extraction and then the indexing into Solr, taking the above recommendations into account.

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly look into that. In the meantime, has it been your experience that onerror skipping or continuing with DIH just does not work? Or do you not even go that route in the first place? Thanks!

Comment: never used the onerror, sorry. I had to index millions of PDF and always had custom code to do it.